# need a list of names to fill a column 2420 down each one each one to be multiplied 55 times and retain list order

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, odt

I have a list of 44 names i need them to fill down a column in multiples of 55

each one to be multiplied 55 times

I'm using libre office

Does that make sense if it doesn't please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This should be a good starting point:

[image]

---

First, you need a formula that would repeat a number N times before changing to the next number (To use in our indexes later). This is where `QUOTIENT` comes to use: it returns whole part of division operation.

So we divide current row index by N, 3 in my example:

`QUOTIENT(ROW(B1),3))`

Which returns 0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2...

(`ROW(B1)` returns index of the cell B1, which is 1)

Now this is not right, as we need the first element to be repeated 3 times, not 2. That's why we need to shift it by one:

`QUOTIENT(ROW(B1)-1,3))`

Which returns 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2...

Now we need to convert these indexes to cell values, and that's where `OFFSET()` comes to play. It takes

1) starting point cell
2) vertical offset
3) horisontal offset

If we pass it our first value cell, A1 (with absolute addressing using `$` which prevents it from changing when you copy this formula), and put result of the previous formula as vertical offset, and 0 as the horizontal offset, this will give the result from the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks very much however it would really help me if you could explain the formula as i dont have time

Comment: Put your 44 names in the column A, change "3" in the formula to "55".